# Can we store relational data in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to convert a application that have relational database as backend. Can I store the data relationaly in HDFS as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for the sake of storing, you can store anything in HDFS. But that won't make any sense. First of all, you should not think of Hadoop as a replacement to your RDBMS(which you are trying to do here). Both are meant for totally different purposes. Hadoop is not a good fit for your transactional, relational or real-time kind of needs. It was meant to serve your offline batch processing needs. So, it's better to analyze your use case properly and then freeze your decision.

As a suggestion I would like to point you to [Hive](http://hive.apache.org). It provides you warehousing capabilities on top of your existing Hadoop cluster. It also provides an SQL like interface to your warehouse, which will make your life much easier if you are coming from SQL background. But again, Hive is also a batch processing system and is not a good fit if you need something real time.

You can have a look at [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org) though, as suggested by abhinav. It's a DB that can run on top of your Hadoop cluster and provides you random, real time read/write access to your data. But you should keep 1 thing in mind that it's a NoSQL db. It doesn't follow the SQL terminologies and conventions. So, you might find it a bit alien initially. You might have to think about issues like how to store your data in a new storage style(columnar) unlike the row style storage of your RDBMS. Otherwise it's not a problem to setup and use it.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Any file can be stored in HDFS. But if you want an SQL type DB you should go for HBASE. If you directly store your data into HDFS you will not be able to store rationality.

Comment: You should add how he can store relational data to a columnar storage like HBase.